# Django: Saving ManyToManyField attribute from form submit

Tags: python, django

I have a view like so:

```
def view(request, ...):
    user = request.user
    company = get_object_or_404(Company, ...)
    group = get_object_or_404(Group, ...) 
    form = TaskCreateForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(company)
        print(group)
        form = TaskCreateForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.creator = user
            form.company = company
            form.group = group
            # So these above attributes aren't actually inputs in the form, but just data passed to the model from things like the user that's sending off the form and the group they're in for example
            form.save()
```

Where creator (the user) and the company are related by ForeignKey to this particular model (Task, which the user is filling in the form for).

The problem is where I write `form.group = group`, and I suspect this may be because the Group has a ManyToMany relationship with the Task model.

I want the 'group' to be one of the many Group objects that will be related to this Task object.

The error occurs upon trying to save the form and is as follows:

> TypeError at /company/task/625377380359841/ 
>   coercing to Unicode: need
>   string or buffer, NoneType found

This would be a great help, thanks!

Edit:
I've also had a look at the save_m2m() method which I thought may be relevant but this did not seem to help unfortunately.

Also, here's my form and model code relating to the TaskCreateForm()...
forms.py:

```
class TaskCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    task_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={
    'placeholder':'Activity name'}), label='Activity', required=True, min_length=3, max_length=60)
    task_priority = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PRIORITY, widget=forms.widgets.Select
    (attrs={'placeholder':'Priority'}), label='Importance', required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        fields = ['task_name', 'task_priority']
```

models.py:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='company_activity',
        verbose_name='Parent Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    group = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='group_activity',
        verbose_name='Related Group', blank=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='activity_creator',
        verbose_name='Created by User', null=True)
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Task')
    task priority = models.CharField(max_length=18, verbose_name='Priority',
        choices=PRIORITY, blank=True, null=True)
    task_slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='Slug', unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Task'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.task_slug

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_slug

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('task-detail', kwargs={'task_slug': self.task_slug, 'co_dom': self.company.domain})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        task_slug(self)
        super(Task, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Full Traceback:

> 905093298449 | company 625377380359841 Internal Server Error:
>   /company/sourceup/opportunities/625377380359841/
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 39, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 187, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 185, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/Users/jayt/grid/company/views.py", line 181, in task_detail
>       act.parent_op.add(opport)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py",
>   line 476, in **get**
>       return self.related_manager_cls(instance)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py",
>   line 783, in **init**
>       (instance, self.source_field_name))   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 572, in **repr**
>       u = six.text_type(self) TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found [25/Jul/2017 17:42:51] "POST
>   /company/task/625377380359841/ HTTP/1.1" 500 81361

Comment: add a print(company) and print(group) and tell me what return

Comment: @MauricioCortazar where to write this?

Comment: After the If request ==post statement

Comment: This printed the unicode for the company, followed by the the unicode for the group. The error follows after.

Comment: Look the terminal and see what printed

Comment: Traceback has been added to the question

Answer (score 2):

you should use `add` method when you try to add `manytomany` field data.

```
form.group.add(group)
form.save()
```

Comment: This returned the same error as before, unfortunately

Comment: Add your model and form code related to TaskCreateForm

Comment: I've updated my question to include the models.py and forms.py for the Task model, thanks

Comment: You forget to return from save method of Activity model

Comment: I have a save method in the model, should I also add save to the form class, and delete the model save method?

Comment: I meant add 'return' here 'return super(Task, self).save(*args, **kwargs)'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150115/discussion-between-neeraj-kumar-and-jayt).

Answer (score 0):

In your `form.save(commit=False)` line, it will return an unsaved Task object (presuming that Task is the model based on the form name).

You can then manipulate the Task object directly prior to saving. Right now you're manipulating the form, which I don't believe is what you want.

So you'd end up with:

```
task = form.save(commit=False)
task.creator = user
task.company = company
task.group.add(group)
task.save()
```

Comment: This still gives me the same error as before; any other ideas why this might be? I've added the full traceback to my question

Comment: You'll need to post some more code, it seems something is missing in what you've posted and where the error occurs in the stack trace. Specifically, the code in company/views.py around line 181

Comment: Line 181 is where the task.group.add(group) is written, I'm not sure what other code I should include